# Column foo not found tablename - Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm using Teradata Express Studio with this query:

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column2 = table2.column3
WHERE table2.column4 IN "foo";
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Executed as Single statement.  Failed [5628 : HY000] Column foo not found in table2 or table1.
```

I am trying to search for an entry where `column4`'s value is foo, but it seems to think that foo is the column name, can anyone assist me with this?

Answer (score 6):

Strings are delimited by single quotes in SQL and you want `=` rather than `IN`:

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1 INNER JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.column2 = table2.column3
WHERE table2.column4 = 'foo';
```

I might also suggest writing this as:

```
SELECT t1.column1
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.column2 = t2.column3 AND t2.column4 = 'foo');
```

This version will not return duplicates, if multiple rows match in `table2`.  That is usually desirable.

Comment: Ah I knew it was something stupid like this. Thanks for the quick answer and the insight!

Answer (score 0):

The operator IN works comparing a value with an array of values it would be something like:

```
WHERE table2.column4 IN ('foo')
```

But an array for just one value might be too much, so I think the best approach would be to use = operator

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
WHERE table1.column2 IN 
     (SELECT table2.column3
      FROM table2 
      WHERE table2.column4 = 'foo');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: In Standard SQL double quoted strings are identifiers, i.e. table/column names. Literals need to be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You in bracket in `IN`

```
SELECT column1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column2 = table2.column3
WHERE table2.column4 IN ("foo");
```

Comment: In Standard SQL double quoted strings are identifiers, i.e. table/column names. Literals need to be enclosed in single quotes.